# Como aplicar upload múltiplo de imagens

Tags: php, sql

Ola tenho esse código que gera no caso adicionadores múltiplos com tudo não estou sabendo como fazer um código de upload de imagens para fazer o upload de todas as imagens que são colocadas no **FILE** do campo de **arquivo[ ]** alguém poderia me ajudar a complementar o código .

No caso estou necessitando que o código faça o upload para a pasta medias, aplique redimensionamento, logo marca e upe todas as imagens e adicione os valores das imagem em **`arquivo`='".$arquivoImagem[$valores]."'** também desde ja agradeço quem poder me ajudar.

Segue abaixo o código que eu fiz com tudo sem o código de upload de imagem. Estou iniciando ainda o meu curso em PHP e tem muita coisa ainda que eu não sei fazer.

Eu só consegui so consegui fazer somente no caso o código de repetição usando o **for** e adicionar os valores direto ao **banco de dados**.

index.php

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="multiplicar.php">
  Coloque aqui o numero de episodios que vc ira adicionar 
  <label>
    <input type="text" name="numeros" id="numeros" style="width:20px;" />

  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="Gerar" value="Gerar" />
  </label>
</form>
```

multiplicar.php

```
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" method="post" action="salvar.php">
    <?php
    $valor = $_POST["numeros"];
    for ($repeticao = 1; $repeticao <= $valor; $repeticao++) { ?>
      <label>
       Nome  <input name="categorias[]" type="text" id="numero" value="" size="10" />  Tipos  <input name="tipos[]" type="text" id="tipos" value="" size="10" /></br>
       Imagem <input name="arquivo[]" type="file" id="arquivo[]" style="border:0px; width:249px;box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #5B5B5B;border-radius:0px; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:14px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px;"/> 
      </label>
    <? }  ?>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
```

salvar.php

```
<?php   
    $categoria = $_POST["categorias"];   
    $tipo = $_POST["tipos"];   
    $arquivoImagem = $_POST["arquivo"];   
    $numeracao = 1;
    foreach($categoria as $valores => $maiorIgual) {


    // Faz a inserção dos dados na MYSQL
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `medias` SET `cat`='".$categoria[$valores]."', `tipos`='".$tipo[$valores]."', `arquivo`='".$arquivoImagem[$valores]."'";
    $consulta = mysql_query($sql);
    if($consulta) {
    echo'<center>';
    echo " Item ".$numeracao++." Cadastrado com Sucesso<br/>";
    }else{
    echo " Item ".$numeracao++." Erro ao cadastrar<br/>";
    echo'</center>';
    }
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Não use `$arquivoImagem = $_POST["arquivo"];` use `$arquivoImagem = $_FILES["arquivo"];`

- `$_FILES['userfile']['name']`

  O nome original do arquivo na máquina do cliente.
- `$_FILES['userfile']['type']`

  O tipo mime do arquivo, se o navegador fornecer essa informação. Um exemplo poderia ser `image/gif`. O tipo mime no entanto não é verificado pelo PHP portanto não considere que esse valor será concedido.
- `$_FILES['userfile']['size']`

  O tamanho, em bytes, do arquivo enviado.
- `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`

  O nome temporário com o qual o arquivo enviado foi armazenado no servidor.
- `$_FILES['userfile']['error']`

  O código de erro associado a esse upload de arquivo.

> Nota: Realmente não vejo motivo para usar `foreach` se a array não é associativa.

Exemplo:

```
foreach ($categoria as $valores => $maiorIgual) {
    $name = $_FILES['file'][$valores]['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file'][$valores]['tmp_name'];

    $error = $_FILES['file'][$valores]['error'];
    if ($error !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo 'Erro ao fazer o upload de:', $name, ' / Erro: ', $error;
    } elseif (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location . $name)) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `medias` SET `cat`='".$categoria[$valores]."', `tipos`='".$tipo[$valores]."', `arquivo`='".$arquivoImagem[$valores]."'";
        //Resto do seu código  
    }
}
```

Recomendo que se não usar arrays associativas, use o `for` normal ao invés de `foreach`

```
$categoria = $_POST["categorias"];   
$tipo = $_POST["tipos"];   
$arquivoImagem = $_POST["arquivo"];

$total = count($arquivoImagem);

if ($total !== count($tipo) || $total !== count($categoria)) {
    //Adicionei este if só como segurança com problemas no formulário
    echo 'Quantidade de itens é invalida';
} else {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
        $name = $_FILES['file'][$i]['name'];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['file'][$i]['tmp_name'];

        $error = $_FILES['file'][$i]['error'];
        if ($error !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            echo 'Erro ao fazer o upload de:', $name, ' / Erro: ', $error;
        } elseif (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location . $name)) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `medias` SET `cat`='".$categoria[$i]."', `tipos`='".$tipo[$i]."', `arquivo`='".$arquivoImagem[$i]."'";
            //Resto do seu código  
        }
    }
}
```

Para entender melhor o uso de arrays em HTML: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Comment: Já resolvi o problema da postagem que foi tirada do ar -__- agradeço ao  Rafael Withoeft pelas ajudas prestadas no chat http://pastebin.com/xaF1PcKy

Comment: @Rodrigo você deve se referir a uma outra pergunta que você fez, que foi fechada, ela não saiu do ar. Devo lhe dizer que as perguntas aqui simplesmente não são fechadas por **maldade**, tem motivos e são conforme as normas da comunidade para uma boa organização e outros critérios. Não leve isto a mal eu mesmo já tive 2 questões minhas fechadas, eu simplesmente li o **"Help"** para entender melhor como formular uma boa pergunta e as refiz (ou editei) para ficarem dentro do **"escopo"**.